# Getting the authenticated user details Laravel 5.2

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

After authenticating a user and return to an appropriate view I want to get hold of the id of the user so I can get some info from the table (users).

How do I do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Auth Facade](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Auth.html) in your controller to get the **ID** of authenticated user.

for eg.-

**SomeController** -

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

//don't forget to include this one
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class SomeController extends Controller
{   

    public function getDetails(){
        //get authenticated user's Id
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user_id = $user->id;
        //other details
        $user_name = $user->name;
        $user_email = $user->email;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Auth::user()->id or auth()->user()->id
```

If you have multiple authentication and you are using guard then you can use

```
Auth::guard('your_guard_name')->user()->id or auth()->guard('your_guard_name')->user()->id
```

N.B: if you use **Auth** then you must include it like **use Auth**

Hope it will help. :) :)